# selenium/ select element inside a sidebar_wrapper

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to have my selenium code click on the search in the sidebar menu and open the search page. But I have had no luck getting it right. All I get is `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[class*=sidebar-wrapper]"}`

Here is how the HTML looks like:
[image]

Here my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://xxxx.com/Login")


username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("xxxxx")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("yyyyyy")

driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()

import time
time.sleep( 5 )

new=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[9]/a")
newpage=new.click()
time.sleep( 10 )

**I tried many different combinations such as:**

#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class*=sidebar-wrapper]").get(3).click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a").click()
#driver.find_element_by_class_name("#sidebar-wrapper > div > div > div.top > div > div:nth-child(2) > a > span.page-name").click()
```

I am not able to figure out where my mistake is when selecting the element. any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share url here ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not, there is a couple of username and password that are needed to get there and those can't be shared. I appreciate your effort and help. I will sleep on it for now to see id I can contact the company and ask them if their have an API that can help me.

Comment: can you share screenshot of that side bar and username fields ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
MyLink = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="top"]/div[@class="pages"]/div[2]/a')))
MyLink.click()
```

list of imports -

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You can also try the below code -

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem);
```

One More method you can try is -

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(yourElement).click().perform()
```

Let me know the outcome.

Comment: I ran it and got below error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automation.py", line 33, in <module>
    MyLink = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="top"]/div[@class="pages"]/div[2]/a')))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ```

Comment: Can you try executing the JavascriptExecutor code which I have just updated?

Comment: Still getting the same timeout error even when I increased it to 40 still got that error. The import is correct. other methods didn't work. I got Unable to locate element error.  the javascript code get a syntax error :(

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not, there is a couple of username and password that are needed to get there and those can't be shared. I appreciate your effort and help. I will sleep on it for now to see id I can contact the company and ask them if their have an API that can help me.